# subprocess goes defunct when ran after thread.start()

Tags: python, python-multithreading, subprocess

I'm hitting a problem where subprocess calls, which should return nearly immediately, end up blocking (the actual child process is defunct and isn't cleaned up).  This appears to only happen when I'm also using threads.  The below program nicely reproduces what I'm seeing.  By running it, you'll see the hostname printed out a bunch of times with the number cycling through the range, until it blocks.  I suspect that once a thread finishes, the defunct process will be cleaned up and then it will happen again.

Anybody have insight as to what's happening and how I can use both threads and subprocesses without this happening?  I'm using Python 2.7.1+ on Ubuntu 11.4.

```
import os
import subprocess
import threading

class DummyThread(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '100'])
        proc.wait()

while True:
    dummy = DummyThread()
    dummy.start()
    for i in range(10):
        print i
        subprocess.check_call(['hostname'])
```

Running this results in a subprocess becoming defuct and blocking the main thread:

```
user     28665 10543  1 22:55 pts/2        python blocker.py
user     28667 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28679 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28691 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28703 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28715 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28727 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28739 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28751 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28763 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28775 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28787 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28799 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        sleep 100
user     28800 28665  0 22:55 pts/2        [hostname] <defunct>
```

Comment: Threadbombing yourself is probably a bad idea no matter what you're trying to do...

Comment: Agreed - in my project, I'm only launching up to 4 threads.  The above reproduces the same behavior though.  Maybe I'm running out of resources or something?

Comment: Can you update the example to launch a limited number of threads, and check that it still causes the problem.

Comment: Maybe you are running out of file descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced this problem on ubuntu 12.04 (python 2.7.3) and on OS X 10.8 (python 2.7.2).

The problem goes away if you set close_fds=True in your calls to subprocess.Popen and subprocess.check_call.

I'm not sure what this means, but it might help someone with a little more knowledge answer the question fully.